# Loading Several Text Files into MongoDB using PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm currently attempting to load *several* text files into MongoDB (they're in JSON format).

I tried using an OS walk, but I seem to be having trouble.
My current method is:

```
>>> import pymongo
>>> import os
>>> import json
>>> from pymongo import Connection
>>> connection = Connection()
>>> db = connection.Austin
>>> collection = db.tweets
>>> collection = db.tweet_collection
>>> db.tweet_collection
Collection(Database(Connection('localhost', 27017), u'Austin'), u'tweet_collection')
>>> collection
Collection(Database(Connection('localhost', 27017), u'Austin'), u'tweet_collection')
>>> tweets = db.tweets
>>> tweet = open(os.path.expanduser('~/Tweets/10_7_2012_12:09-Tweets.txt'),'r')
>>> for line in tweet:
...      d = json.loads(line)
...      tweets.insert(d)
...
```

For inserting a single Tweet.
I want to be able to open multiple files and run that same piece of code, namely the for loop that turns the JSON into python dictionaries and inserts it into the collection, autonomously.

Does anyone have a solid example of how to do this, complete with an explanation?

While we're on the topic, I'm attempting to use MongoDB with a poor understanding of databases (silly and stupid, I know), but MongoDB can support multiple instances of databases at the same time, and stores collections, which are groups of documents, and you can insert individual documents, correct?

(Also, please ignore the inconsistency between the collections tweets and tweet_collection.. I was just experimenting to get a better understanding)

Comment: Is there single/multiple tweets per file? (as the name *Tweets.txt implies > 1)

Comment: Aye, each file contains multiple tweets, but each tweet has its own line. Sorry for the slow response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**untested**

```
from glob import iglob
import os.path
import pymongo
import json

for fname in iglob(os.path.expanduser('~/Tweets/*.txt')):
    with open(fname) as fin:
        tweets = json.load(fin)
        for tweet in tweets:
            db.tweets.insert(tweet)
```

This loops over all the filenames in '~/Tweets/*.txt', opens it, and loads 1 or more tweets from the file into a Python dictionary - note the use of `.load` instead of `.loads` - the difference being `.load()` takes a file-like object while `.loads()` takes a string. Then for each tweet, inserts that into the database. (Note I've used `db.tweets.insert` instead of `tweets = db.tweets` as I personally find the 'db' prefix a reminder it's a DB op and not some other object)

As to your understanding on MongoDB re: DB's/collections/documents - yes, you're correct.

Comment: Well, I tried it, and it gives the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "masspush.py", line 13, in <module>
    tweets = json.load(fin)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 278, in load
    **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 369, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 218 column 1 (char 2590 - 554222)

Sorry for formatting. @Jon Clements

Comment: Can you copy and post that bit and some of the surrounding data?

Comment: Do you mean within the text file itself?
The issue is that there are ~500 files, and I'm not sure *which* file it refers to that has the extra data.

Comment: Catch the exception and print fname?

Comment: I caught the exception - it turns out that all of them are doing it... Awesome. So, for the sake of space, is the extra data line 2 column 1 or line 218 column 1? Or is that line 2 TO line 218 column 1?

And even line 2 is roughly 2,000 characters :|

Comment: @KalîlÁrmstrøng Debugging doesn't really work via S/O comments - I think you have to work through it to isolate the problem, or post it somewhere like pastebin/dpaste or whatever... so others can have a look at it